# Parallel generating of triangular graph distance matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-foreach

I have an array of n graphs and I have to generate a triangular n x n matrix with the distance between the graphs. 
I made the non-parallel program, meaning I have the function that calculates the no. of vertices for every pair of 2 graphs of size n1 and n2, No_MaxCommonSubgraph(graph1,graph2,n1,n2)
and I have 2 nesting for, and that construct the matrix. It works ok.
I transformed the first for into foreach, and I have

```
foreach(i <- 1:n-1)
    for(j in i:n){
       nn <- No_MaxCommonSubgraph(graph1,graph2,n1,n2)
       mat[i,j] <- max(n1,n2)-nn ##this should construct the matrix
}
```

The problem is that when I get out of foreach, the matrix mat has all values NA.
I tried to write the matrix file into foreach, after the for j, line by line, but it writes the lines in different order, as the lines are calculated by the cores. And sometimes write a line inside another line.

I use a Linux comp. with 12 cores and I may use another comp. with 8 cores.
For graph size 8, I have 11117 graphs and I have to go till size 9 or 10.
I'm new into R.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `foreach`:

```
 m2 <-foreach(i=1:(len-1), .combine='rbind', .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {     
        f_foreach(erg, i, len)}
```

so

1. use `%dopar%` in `foreach`
2. function "`f_foreach()`" returns a vector and by using "`.combine='rbind'`" in `foreach` it combines the vectors to form the matrix m2 as result of `foreach`.
3. inside `f_foreach()` is the second for